# Microsoft Azure Synapse deployed into Managed Resource Group cannot write to Storage Account when invoked via Trigger

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-managed-identity

**UPDATE:** We are deploying Synapse as part of a Managed Application, which means it is running in a Managed Resource Group. It appears as though this mechanism is causing the problem.

**Problem Statement:**

- Deployed a Synapse Workspace into a Managed Resource Group as part of a Managed Azure Application
- Running a Notebook via the UI (with the Run button whilst editing) works as expected and performs a simple Read and Write to the Synapse Meta folder
- Running the SAME Notebook via a Pipeline + Trigger fails with 403 HTTP error on WRITE or DELETE (READ works fine, interestingly)
- Configuration as per How to set up access control for your Synapse workspace - Azure Synapse Analytics | Microsoft Docs
- I repeat the same experiment with a manually created Storage Account OUTSIDE of the Managed Resource Group with the exact same permissions and it works fine

**My understanding:**

- The DevOps Service Principal that created the infra and workspace is set as the Synapse Worksapce initialWorkspaceAdminObjectId.
- The Workspace MSI automatically creates a managed service principal on the Container where it will write the Synapse meta data.
- When we run the notebook through the UI it is using AD passthrough, so it is running it as the logged on user, which allows writing to the data container.
- When we run via a trigger, it is running on behalf of the Synapse MSI, which for some reason is not authenticating correctly, despite the configuration being correct.
- Something is happening behind the scenes with the Managed Resource Group mechanism that Synapse is not liking

**Error:**

```
Operation on target TestReadWrite failed: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o230.save. : java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "This request is denied to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, PUT, https://cmsdlrylcf3v7bw5et4.dfs.core.windows.net/synapse/user/trusted-service-user/default-csv/_temporary/0?resource=directory&timeout=90, AuthorizationPermissionDenied, "This request is denied to perform this operation using this permission. RequestId:91d104cb-101f-0030-61c2-15f3d3000000 Time:2022-01-30T10:18:18.1886398Z" at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.checkException(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:1185) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.mkdirs(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:477) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:2288) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:382) at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:201) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:173) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:188) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:218) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:256) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:253) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:214) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:148) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:147) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:995) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:112) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:176) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:94) at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:67) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:995) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:444) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:416) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:294) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Running through UI can write to the storage account.

[image]

However running the SAME code through a Pipeline and Trigger fails:

[image]

[image]

**Synapse Workspace Access Control**

- Synapse MSI has Synapse Administrator RBAC
- Service Principal that deployed the Synapse Workspace (set as initialWorkspaceAdminObjectId) has Synapse Administrator
- synwspace-ylcf3v7bw5et4 - Azure Synapse Analytics

[image]

**Storage Account Service IAM**

- Synapse MSI has Owner Synapse MSI has Storage Account Data Contributor
- Service Principal that deployed the Synapse Workspace
  (set as initialWorkspaceAdminObjectId) has Owner
- Service Principal has Storage Account Data Contributor / Reader

[image]

**Storage Account DataLake ACL on Synapse Container**

- Synapse MSI has Owner
- Synapse MSI has Storage Account Data Contributor / Reader

**Linked Services**

- Linked Service to Storage Gen 2 connects via Storage Account key (passes Test Connection)
  [image]

The summary of all of this is that I cannot use a Synapse workspace deployed via DevOps as the permissions are not set correctly - can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are your storage networking settings? Does the pipeline run from a trigger succeed when you open the storage firewall to all networks temporarily?

Comment: When run manually it is AD passthrough (sure) but when triggered it is the Synapse MSI - are you sure about that? Running it as the logged in user is not an equivalent test because it's a different user. When you use IaC to deploy the notebook & run, is there a specific config for which service account to "run as" or are you just assuming it defaults to running as the workspace admin? I wouldn't assume that. Try to use click-ops to schedule or otherwise trigger a notebook execution that runs as that same service account you think it is running as.

Comment: Hi @Davos, yes, it is an assumption. If it is NOT the Synapse MSI when running triggers unattended, then what account would it be?

Comment: @GregGalloway It is alreadyset to All networks - no VPN or anything interesting

Comment: What do you mean "Synapse workspace deployed via DevOps"? With Terraform?

Comment: @Rodney conversely, if it is the Synapse MSI, how can you manually simulate that scenario? Your theory is that the Terraform deployment is to blame; to prove that narrow down to just that. Do a manual job deployment vs IaC deployment but in both cases automate the job to make sure it is NOT passing through your user. If that proves unfruitful then consider the Terraform provider is just a wrapper over the API, so you could try using the API directly. If that works then maybe it is a bug or missing config in the Terraform provider.

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda in this case it is with an ARM template and AZ CLI for creating the artifacts.

Comment: @Davos So I have simplified the problem down to the simplest possible configuration. Running through Notebook works fine, running the Notebook through Pipeline 403 on Storage Account access. I'm just trying a few different mounting options (Account Key, Linked Service, SaS etc) to see if it makes a difference

Comment: I have found the problem: Synapse and the Storage account are deployed via ARM into a Managed Resource Group as part of a Managed Application. For some reason, when the pipeline tries to invoke the notebook and write to a Storage Account in a MANAGED RG iut is failing. As soon as I use the same code and set up (and Workspace) on a Storage Account NOT in a Managed RG then it works... more details to follow shortly

Comment: Is the storage account being created as part of the same resource group? Are you missing a managed private endpoint?

Comment: Yes, Storage Account is created in same RG and attached to Synapase. It is not in a VPN

Comment: FYI, we have found the problem - I have updated the answer. An addition line of code is needed when inside of a Managed RG

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the problem is that Synapse writing to a Storage Account inside of a **Managed Resource Group** behaves differently to Synapse writing to a Storage Account that is NOT in a Managed Resource Group, albeit with the exact same configuration and permissions.

Kudus to Microsoft Support Engineer Fangfang who helped find this workaround!

If you are writing to a Storage Account in a Managed Resource Group you have to add this line of code to your Notebooks to get your Pipelines to work:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<WSName>.dfs.core.windows.net", "SharedKey")
```

You can leave this out when writing to a Storage Account in a normal RG.

Reference:  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/abfs.html

However, a new problem was found where a Synapse Workspace can be created via ARM, but the Notebooks and artifacts cannot be deployed into a Managed Resource Group where it is in a different AD Tenancy (which is usually the case in a mMnaged Application). Unless a workaround can be found, this means that Synapse would be unusable within a Managed Application where large scale analytics are needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but I believe I have an answer here. I've seen AuthorizationPermissionDenied bubble up when an underlying operation is being blocked by the Managed Resource Group's deny assignment. I'm not a synapse expert but it looks like your workaround works because it defaults the notebook to using keys, which are not governed by the deny assignment, instead of the identity, which is. It also explains why WRITE and DELETE wouldn't work initially, but READ would, as the deny assignment allows all read control/data actions by default. As well, if you're kicking things off in the azure portal within the publisher tenant, you're most likely a user that is in the security group that owns the MRG, which is also excluded from the deny assignment.

To your follow up issue of not being able to deploy notebooks and artifacts in the MRG, what exactly is occurring? It's possible something related to the deny assignment is happening there as well. If it's a more complicated scenario of trying to push something from the publisher tenant in to a customer tenant, using operations that depend on managed identities, it most likely won't work, as they do not work cross-tenant. We also generally believe the Synapse resource tries to authenticate the admin object with the publisher tenant, not the customer tenant where the identity would live- which is another layer of problems here. That said we have gotten Synapse working with SQL scripts in a managed resource group.

If you've figured out more around these limitations I'd be curious to hear them, as we're working around similar edge cases.